Azure CI/CD pipeline not running successfully with run script in swift
I am new for create CI/CD pipeline in azure. I try to create pipeline for my swift project but when try to execute run script with firebase crash analytics it going to failed.
script code is below
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
fi

YML file
# Xcode
# Build, test, and archive an Xcode workspace on macOS.
# Add steps that install certificates, test, sign, and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xcode

trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
  paths:
    include:
      - ProjectName/*

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'pods | "$(Agent.OS)" | Podfile.lock'
    path: 'Pods'
    cacheHitVar: 'PODS_CACHE_RESTORED'
- task: CocoaPods@0
  displayName: 'pod install using the CocoaPods task with defaults'
  condition: ne(variables.PODS_CACHE_RESTORED, 'true')

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    scheme: ''
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'
    xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, default, specifyPath
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Build and Sign'
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    sdk: '$(sdk)'
    scheme: '$(scheme)'
    signingOption: 'auto'
    teamId: $(teamId)
    packageApp: false
    destinationPlatformOption: 'ios'
    configuration: '$(configuration)' # only testable for Debug with current config
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'
    xcodeVersion: 'default'
    args: '-derivedDataPath $(build.Repository.LocalPath)/xxxx/'




Make sure the paths to folders are set correctly in your Azure Devops yaml code:-
trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
  paths:
    include:
      - ProjectName/*

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'pods | "$(Agent.OS)" | Podfile.lock'
    path: 'Pods'
    cacheHitVar: 'PODS_CACHE_RESTORED'
  
- task: CocoaPods@0
  displayName: 'pod install'
  condition: ne(variables.PODS_CACHE_RESTORED, 'true')

- script: |
    if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
    "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
    fi
  displayName: 'Run Firebase Crashlytics script'
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'Release')

- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Build and Sign'
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    scheme: '<YourSchemeName>'  # Replace with your actual scheme name
    signingOption: 'auto'
    teamId: '<YourTeamId>'  # Replace with your actual team ID
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcworkspace'  # Adjust the path to your workspace if needed
    xcodeVersion: 'default'
    args: '-derivedDataPath $(build.Repository.LocalPath)/build'

You can directly use the default yaml code to build your swift project like below:-

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    scheme: 'FirebaseSwiftExample'
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    configuration: 'Release'
    xcWorkspacePath: '**/*.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace'
    workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/FirebaseSwiftExample
    xcodeVersion: 'default'

Make sure you have GoogleService-Info.plist in your repository for the project to get built successfully.
